# My Compiler can't read certain classes

Tags: java

I wanted to ask basic question which irritated me for a while. 
It is about class types of JAVA. Well, I am reading some beginner's book about programming and practicing to write programs the book gives. At this point, that book states about certain types of classes such as "RectangleComponent", "Day" that my compiler, Bluej, can't compile it by stating "there are no such classes". What should I do about this? Why is Bluej stating it incorrect while there are certainly these classes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should I update or make changes in my compiler? What can be wrong with it?

Comment: Classes in Java belong in _packages_. If you try to use a class in a different package from the one your class is defined in, you have to either: 1. import that class (or package), or 2. specify the class's fully-qualified name.

Comment: I imported the class by writing java.awt.RectangleComponent. But it still is not working

Comment: You're going to need to show us some of your code if you're getting specific errors.

Comment: Is not the "RectangleComponent" class's fully qualified name that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes referenced in the book you are reading may often be example classes for helping understand concepts.  If you have not created the classes explicitly yourself, or created a target containing these classes, they will not be understood by the compiler.  If you want to follow along with an example that utilizes "RectangleComponent.java", you'll need to create and implement these classes yourself.

Comment: @StackFlowed: It is an answer although you want it to be a comment.

Comment: without knowing the level of knowledge this user has, it was hard to know where exactly to put my response.  I anticipate that the user is a beginner, so putting this simple explanation as an answer seemed appropriate.  I could see it going either way though.

Comment: @Ivan I agree with you. In my book it says "to extend" JComponent class. As you said I need to create RectangleComponent class as an extension. But the question is how? Can I just write "public class RectangleComponent extends JComponent" this line at the beginning? But that is also incorrect.

Comment: @S.Dovra are you also importing the library that holds the `JComponent` class? (i.e. before `public class...` do you have something like `import javax.swing.JComponent;` )

Comment: Yes, I corrected my error. I put the "import"s to the classes. Now it is OK. I compiled it but I can't view it after compilation. The program is just two rectangle drawn. On Bluej, when I try to view it, there are so many options and each of the requires method code.

Comment: Ok, It seems like you got it working now.  If you have a separate issue(s), you should create a separate question.  Did @IvanAnderson's answer help you solve the problem? (then mark it as such) - if it was one of the comments that led you to the answer, then ask the user to add the comment as an answer and then mark it as such.